# getting the values of array from javascript to java as list

Tags: java, javascript, arrays, list, dwr

```
var catids = new Array();
```

I have a catids array where i store the checked checkbox values like the below one.

```
cat = $("input[name=catChkBox]:checked").map(function () {
  return $(this).data('name');
  }).get().join(",");
```

the cat variable forms something like this 1,2,3..

I want to send this "cat" to a java method and print those values.

I pass the values to java through a dwr call like this

```
  DataHandler.getTasks( categories, {callback:function(data){
  }, errorHandler:function(){
  },async:false
   });
```

I have configured dwr for pojo. should I configure anything for parameters?

I tried the below code but I didn't get anything.

```
public List<Facade> getTasks(String myIds){
 String[] ids = catids .split(",");
 System.out.println("-------size of cat id------------" + myIds.length);
 for (int i=0; i<myIds.length;i++)
 System.out.println(myIds[i]);
```

//finally it will return a pojo which i l be receiving it in data of dwr call.

-------size of cat id------------ is 1
myIds[i] prints nothing

I need it as an integer back. 
What mistake am I doing ?

Comment: You only left out the most important part: HOW do you send this "cat" to java?

Comment: Please enter some example usage od `getTasks` method - how categoriesIds looks before method call and how it should look?

Answer (score 2):

I will do it in this way.

1. JavaScript creates json object like this `{"categoryIds": [1,2,3,4,5]}`
2. Java converter convert json to java POJO object using for example [Gson](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) or [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/) library.
3. After convert you can work with java POJO object which have list of categories.

If you use this solution your code will be more clear and you will be able to share more objects between JavaScript and Java using the same clear solution.

Example (pseudo code)

CategorList class

```
public class CategoryList {
    private ArrayList<Category> categoryList;
    // getters and setters
}
```

Converter

```
public class CategoryListConverter {
    public CategoryList convert(String json) {
        Gson g = new Gson();
        CategoryList cl = g.fromJson(json, CategoryList.class);

        return cl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried the code it workd fine

```
   getTasks("1,2,3");
```

check what the value of categoriesIds is sent to getTask

Answer (score 0):

Send this as a `form parameter` from webpage. Then get this from `HttpServletRequest request` object in java.

```
request.getParameter('categoryId');
```